# Understanding file handling in hadoop

Tags: hadoop

I am new to Hadoop ecosystem with some basic idea. Please assist on following queries to start with:

1. If the file size (file that am trying to copy into HDFS) is very big and unable to accommodate with the available commodity hardware in my Hadoop ecosystem system, what can be done?  Will the file wait until it gets an empty space or the there is an error?
2. How to find well in advance or predict the above scenario will occur in a Hadoop production environment where we continue to receive files from outside sources?
3. How to add a new node to a live HDFS ecosystem? There are many methods but I wanted to know which files I need to alter?
4. How many blocks does a node have? If I assume that a node is a CPU with storage(HDD-500 MB), RAM(1GB) and a processor(Dual Core). In this scenario is it like 500GB/64? assuming that each block is configured to hold 64 GB RAM
5. If I `copyFromLocal` a 1TB file into HDFS, which portion of the file will be placed in which block in which node? How can I know this?
6. How can I find which record/row of the input file is available in which file of the multiple files split by Hadoop?
7. What are the purpose of each xmls configured? (core-site.xml,hdfs-site.xml & mapred-site.xml). In a distributed environment, which of these files should be placed in all the slave Data Nodes?
8. How to know how many map and reduce jobs will run for any read/write activity? Will the write operation always have 0 reducer?

Apologize for asking some of the basic questions. Kindly suggest methods to find answers for all of the above queries.

Comment: Have you read any hadoop books or official documentation? Many of these questions are answered there. As it stands this post is very broad

Comment: Yes Cricket I realized it after posting, thanks for looking into it.